# Join two different databases by name in R

Tags: r, database, join, merge

I'm kinda new to R and I need to join two different databases by the teacher's name, so I know that the teacher in database 1 is present in the database 2. I need to join them by their last name + the first letter of their first name.

First database looks something like this:

```
    NAME            ID
JOSE SANTOS         2
MARIA RIOS          3
JULIANA SILVA       7
```

The second one looks like this:

```
         NAME                      GENDER
TIAGO MELO                         MALE
JOSE FRAGOSO SANTOS                MALE
JULIANA DOS SANTOS SILVA           FEMALE
MARIANA ALMEIDA                    FEMALE
```

So, I need to know if the person in database 1 is in database 2 by their names. So it looks like this:

```
         NAME                   GENDER         PRESENT
TIAGO MELO                       MALE             NA
JOSE FRAGOSO SANTOS              MALE             YES
JULIANA DOS SANTOS SILVA        FEMALE            YES
MARIANA ALMEIDA                 FEMALE            NA
```

I've already tried to merge, but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I think it's likely easiest to extract the first-initial and last-name up-front, then use simple `merge`/join mechanics.

### base R

```r
df1$quux <- gsub("^(.).* ([^ ]*) *$", "\\1 \\2", df1$NAME)
df2$quux <- gsub("^(.).* ([^ ]*) *$", "\\1 \\2", df2$NAME)
df1
#            NAME ID     quux
# 1   JOSE SANTOS  2 J SANTOS
# 2    MARIA RIOS  3   M RIOS
# 3 JULIANA SILVA  7  J SILVA
df2
#                       NAME GENDER      quux
# 1               TIAGO MELO   MALE    T MELO
# 2      JOSE FRAGOSO SANTOS   MALE  J SANTOS
# 3 JULIANA DOS SANTOS SILVA FEMALE   J SILVA
# 4          MARIANA ALMEIDA FEMALE M ALMEIDA
```

From here,

```r
merge(df1, df2, by = "quux", all.y = TRUE)
#        quux        NAME.x ID                   NAME.y GENDER
# 1  J SANTOS   JOSE SANTOS  2      JOSE FRAGOSO SANTOS   MALE
# 2   J SILVA JULIANA SILVA  7 JULIANA DOS SANTOS SILVA FEMALE
# 3 M ALMEIDA          <NA> NA          MARIANA ALMEIDA FEMALE
# 4    T MELO          <NA> NA               TIAGO MELO   MALE
```

and you can determine `PRESENT` with `!is.na(ID)`.

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
left_join(
  mutate(df2, quux = gsub("^(.).* ([^ ]*) *$", "\\1 \\2", NAME)),
  mutate(df1, quux = gsub("^(.).* ([^ ]*) *$", "\\1 \\2", NAME)),
  by = "quux"
) %>%
  mutate(PRESENT = !is.na(ID))
#                     NAME.x GENDER      quux        NAME.y ID PRESENT
# 1               TIAGO MELO   MALE    T MELO          <NA> NA   FALSE
# 2      JOSE FRAGOSO SANTOS   MALE  J SANTOS   JOSE SANTOS  2    TRUE
# 3 JULIANA DOS SANTOS SILVA FEMALE   J SILVA JULIANA SILVA  7    TRUE
# 4          MARIANA ALMEIDA FEMALE M ALMEIDA          <NA> NA   FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use mutate from the `dplyr` package, assuming your first dataframe is `df1` and the second is `df2` :

```
library(dplyr)

df2=mutate(df2,"PRESENT"=ifelse(df2$NAME %in% df1$NAME,"YES",NA))
```

Comment: This won't work because the names are not exactly the same in the two data bases (one includes middle names).